# Adding init data via Bootstrap.groovy to application

Tags: grails

My domain layer looks like that:

```
@Resource(uri='/product')
class BasicProduct {

    String title
    String description
    Double price
    Date creationDate
    Date changedDate

    static constraints = {
        //everything is by default NotNull
        title(blank: false, unique: true)
        description(blank: false)
        price(blank: false, inList: [5,15,25,50,100])
        creationDate(min: new Date())
    }

}
```

My `Bootstrap.groovy` contains that code:

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
         new BasicProduct(title: "Product1", description:"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba", price:5).save()
         new BasicProduct(title: "Product2", description:"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba", price:75).save()
         new BasicProduct(title: "Product3", description:"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba", price:50).save()
         new BasicProduct(title: "Product4", description:"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba", price:25).save()
         new BasicProduct(title: "Product5", description:"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba", price:15).save()

         println "initializing data..."
    }
```

However when I open the `\product` url I do not see any data.

Any ideas why?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: use .save(failOnError: true) and I suspect you will see something about your creationDate on your domain being null.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore yes thats true. However I do not want to create the creationDate by myself how to let grails create it. Is the constraint wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your dates you can do:

```
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated 

static mapping = {
  autoTimestamp true
}
```

Comment: No need to explicitly specify autoTimestamp true